# Reset / Reuse / Clone cURL Multi Handle

Tags: php, curl

I have a specific problem which requires me to reuse cURL multi handles. Is there a way to do that? I tried to use

```
curl_copy_handle()
```

And it did not work saying

```
 curl_copy_handle(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource
```

Which is not totally unexpected. Is there a way to reuse or clone a cURL multi handle?

Edit: Calling

```
clone
```

Also does not work

```
Fatal error:  __clone method called on non-object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with a single built-in function.

As you creating the original cURL multi handle, right before each `curl_multi_add_handle()` call, save a copy of each easy (regular) handle in an array A with `curl_copy_handle()`.

Then, when you need to re-use the multi handle:

- Create a new empty one with `curl_multi_init()`
- Loop through each element of A
- In the loop, use `curl_multi_add_handle()` to add a copy (again, with `curl_copy_handle()`) of each easy handle to the new multi handle

Comment: What I ended up doing was using the original multicURL handle, but removing all cURL handles and adding them back. This was much faster than calling curl_multi_init again.